# ufw , deny me to access to shared folder

Tags: ufw

I have deployed ubuntu server 16.4 and use it as a shared folder server, I configure the server but the problem is the ufw , when I enable the ufw can't access my shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open ports 445 and 139.

This can be done in UFW if you go to rules, press the plus sign and then preconfigured and then select SAMBA.

[image]

or the equivalent on the command line

```
sudo ufw allow Samba
```